# Requisição com Método Post e CURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando recuperar os dados de uma API no servidor utilizando CURL, entretanto, parece que não está indo os dados do POST

```
<?php

$postfields = array(
                        'login' => 'login',
                        'senha' => 'senha'
                    );

// página que receberá a requisição post
$pagina = 'http://apps.meusapps.m/api';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pagina );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );

curl_exec( $ch );

curl_close();
```

Retorno:

> {"message":"Voce precisa fornecer os dados de login e senha","status":false}

Answer (score 1):

não sei se depois de 1 ano vai te ajudar mas talvez alguém ainda tenha essa duvida, a url provavelmente precisa de um HTTP Basic Auth, pra isso basta adicionar, as basta substituir as variáveis $user e $pass pelos tokens que são fornecidos pela API.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($user.':'.$pass),
        'Content-Type: application/json',
           ));
```